# use regular expression to find substrings in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, .net-core, substring

I am new to regex in c# and i am trying to figure out a way to pull data from a user input string. So far I have tried to use the Regex.Matches and the Regex.Split but no matter what i try i can't seem to understand how to write my regular expression to find what i want. Here is the input string example:

```
-new -task:my task 1 -body:this is the body for task one -priority:1
```

i would like to split this so that i can get everything that is in between the :(colon) and the -
so for example, i would like for one of my matches/split results to be: my task 1
and then another match to be: this is the body for task one
and so on. Thank you

Comment: is it for the arguments of a console app, maybe?

Comment: I'd be easier to use [```string.Split```](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) on the ```-``` and then - on each entry - ```string.Spit``` again using the ```:```.

Comment: When starting with regex I recommend using some basic tutorial like https://regexone.com/, once you know the bascis a simple "Edi" like https://regex101.com/ should be  a good sand box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Match in Csharp

```
   string input = "-new - task:my task 1 - body:this is the body for task one -priority:1";
  string pattern = @":(.*?)-";
            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            while (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
                match = match.NextMatch();
            }
```

Comment: this is perfect, thank you. Just a quick question. Are capture groups always used for "capture stuff between these symbols" because up until now, i haven't found a tutorial that really adequately explains capture groups, but they way you used them here makes me think they are meant to match expressions between other expressions/literals. thank you.

Comment: Group property in match is used to get collection of groups that are matched by regex.
You may read more from [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

This is probably parsable with Regex. But regex has the downside of, while being nifty. It has a heavy cognitive load to understand. Since this only very little information being inputted (and not a huge file with allot of cases you need to shift through)

And I believe you have full control over how the format is being inputted into the program. I'd advice you not to use regex. And just to a string.split in the '-'. And simply interpret each argument as you walk over the array.

This should be much easier to maintain in the long run. Because if you have to ask about the regex online now, think about what will happen if you have to maintain the code again in the future.